# BootStrap Small Devices, Toggle Menu Background Colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Image tells more than 100 words.

So I'm trying to get background to that navbar dropdown for small devices (Please see image bellow). Also I'm **not** using Bootstrap default theme css file. Please note, this is only used, when device is too small to see full navigation bar for the website.

Please note, I'm using FontAwesome to provide icons!

HTML:

```
    <div class="body-top-padding">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top container marginaali" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">(Valinnat)</span>
                <i class="fa fa-bars valikko-icon-vari" aria-hidden="true" id="menuIconColor"></i>
            </button>
            <span class="logo"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right menuValikkoYksi">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.menuValikkoYksi {
  margin-right: 20%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
.item, .active, .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}
.body-top-padding {
  padding-top: 115px;
}
.marginaali {
  margin-top: 25px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.karuselli-ico {
  color: #202020;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 45px;
  background-image: url(/public/images/logo-min.gif);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 64px;
}
#menuIconColor {
  color: #fff;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `navbar-default` class to your `navbar`, or you can just set background-color yourself with this css:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Comment: That is not looking good. With that solution I will lose menu bar transparency. https://gyazo.com/5c29def4dd72438d53a4461f26d6d523

Comment: Then leave .navbar transparent and set background-color to .navbar-collapse

Answer (score 0):

There Are different ways to do, if you want to do it on specific width, use: *media query*.

Use Following code:

```
@media(max-width:420px){
.nav{
background-color: #ccc;
border-color: #000;
}
}
```

Comment: Even in this case, you will have that ugly white bar, when it's collapsed. If it's possible to avoid that? Please see: https://i.gyazo.com/104dcf3d329645a2968ae2ec9c212603.png